# Timediff minus breaktime with jquery in 24h format

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for for an example to calculate the timediff between to TIMES (24h) minus break time in H:m format;

Starttime: 08:30
Endtime: 17:30
Break: 01:50 (means break time 110 Minute Break time)

Netto working hours should be: 07:10 (7h10m) and 7.17 as decimal..

Is there an example?
I will appreciate your input.
Thanks

Comment: did you suceed in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are others ways to do that but to calc this time difference you have first to transform yours timestamps into seconds, then after you calculate it as seconds, transform to timestamp again to show up. like in the code:

HTML:

```
<html>
  <label>Start Time</label><br>
  <input id="start" value="08:30"><br>
  <label>End Time</label><br>
  <input id="end" value="17:30"><br>
  <label>Break Time</label><br>
  <input id="breaktime" value="01:50"><br>
  <br>
  <label>Difference Time</label><br>
  <input id="diff"><br>
  <label>As decimal</label><br>
  <input id="decimals">
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
function getTime(seconds) {

  //an hour contains 60 * 60 = 3600 seconds
  //a minut contains 60 seconds
  //the amount of seconds we have left
  var leftover = seconds;

  //how many full hours fits in the amount of leftover seconds
  var hours = Math.floor(leftover / 3600);
  
  //how many seconds are left
  leftover = leftover - (hours * 3600);

  //how many minutes fits in the amount of leftover seconds
  var minutes = Math.floor(leftover / 60);

  //how many seconds are left
  leftover = leftover - (minutes * 60);
  return ('0' + hours).slice(-2) + ':' + minutes;
}
function getSeconds(timestamp) {
  var hms = timestamp + ':00';   // your input string
  var a = hms.split(':'); // split it at the colons

  // minutes are worth 60 seconds. Hours are worth 60 minutes.
  var seconds = (+a[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+a[1]) * 60 + (+a[2]); 
  return seconds;
}
function getDecimals(timestamp) {
    var hms = timestamp + ':00';   // your input string
  var a = hms.split(':'); // split it at the colons
  //To get the total decimal hours we use the formula: h = hours + (minutes / 60) + (seconds / 3600).
  var decimal = (+a[0]) + ((+a[1]) / 60) + ((+a[2]) / 3600);
  return decimal.round(2)
}
var endTime = document.getElementById("end").value;
var startTime = document.getElementById("start").value;
var breakTime = document.getElementById("breaktime").value;
var diff = getSeconds(endTime) -  getSeconds(startTime) - getSeconds(breakTime);

document.getElementById("diff").value = getTime(diff);
document.getElementById("decimals").value = getDecimals(getTime(diff));
```

you can check in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1ovdbf28/1/

Comment: Nice! Please if you can set the answer as the solution, i'll be thankful